# jQuery, how to keep a div active even using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am working on a comments system and I have made it nice with jQuery, I have a problem. I made it fetch the DB stuff every 2000 miliseconds (2 seconds). And here is the problem, when a user clicks "report comment" another div with a message will show, but after the 2 seconds it disappears, and I'm assuming it's because the setInterval is refreshing the content.

But here is what I've done.

NOTE: I put this part of the code within the while() function in PHP so it loops with all the other comments, and I've assigned them with a uniqueID.

```
<script type="test/javascript">
    $("#<?= $lc['uniqueid']; ?>").click(function() {
        $("#report<?= $lc['uniqueid']; ?>").fadeIn();
    });
</script>
```

And here is the script where it refreshes the content ext, (it's on the bottom of my webpage by the way)

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('serverinfo.php?showcomments=<?= $id; ?>', function(data) {
        $('#showcomments').html(data);
    });
}, 2000);
```

So if anyone would know how to ignore the div that shows up when a user clicks report to be removed, I'd appreciate it! thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just append the new items instead of replacing everything?

Comment: @epascarello - I'm sorry, but how would I do that?

Comment: Appending new comments and sending only the required information from the server would even increase speed, if only slightly... And considering @MohammadAdil's comment (removed now but said "`.get` is async!"), it would be good to use `setTimeout` at the end of your handler and wrap it in a known function. This is to prevent that two requests overwrite each other - just a minor fix though.

Comment: change your backend to only return new items from a certain timestamp. And you use the append method to add them to the list.

Comment: You definitely want to switch from setInterval to setTimeout with a named function, that will prevent the browser from crashing when it can't get a response after 2 seconds, or the tab loses focus due to requests stacking up.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is conditional update of your content. ie, when user clicks "report comment" add a line

```
$('#showcomments').addClass("comment-active");
```

Then make your update conditional:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.get('serverinfo.php?showcomments=<?= $id; ?>', function (data) {

        if (!$('#showcomments').hasClass("comment-active")) {
            $('#showcomments').html(data);
        }

    });
}, 2000);
```

And to add, of course, delete the class when the report comment is closed.

```
$('#showcomments').removeClass("comment-active");
```